# How to refresh DataGrid in xaml/uwp application

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I'm looking for a simple way to refresh a DataGrid in my xaml/uwp application because external events sometimes affect rows in my grid. As an example, I have a row with a button in it that needs to be disabled if internet connectivity is lost.

I know how to receive a callback when connectivity changes, and I know how to set up the button in such a way that its `IsEnabled` property is set or cleared according to the state of connectivity.

I can't figure out how to get the grid to refresh that property when the network state changes.

Comment: We want to know what effort you put into it toward solving the problem. Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it. Please see "[ask]" and "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)".

Comment: For clarification, are you saying that you are able to detect a network change successfully, and that you can update the IsEnabled property successfully based on that network change, but that the grid doesn't reflect that change?

Comment: More or less, yes. The IsEnabled flag isn't tied to a property on my object though, it is set using a binding to an IValueConverter. So I don't know what I'm supposed to do in order to get the DataGrid to re-evaluate the converter's value.

Comment: I came up with a workaround of removing and re-assigning the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid, but it only works if I do it on separate invocations of the main loop, which I've accomplished by using two separate RunAsync methods. It's an ugly solution because you can see the grid clear for a moment before it reloads.

Answer (score 0):

> How to refresh DataGrid in xaml/uwp application

You could use [`NetworkHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.connectivity.networkhelper?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) NetworkChanged event to detect the network status then make network status flag in current `DataContext` and bind it to `DataGridTextColumn` `Binding` property.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
{
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
}
private bool _isConnected;
public bool IsConnected
{
    get
    {
        return _isConnected;
    }
    set
    {
        _isConnected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

 NetworkHelper.Instance.NetworkChanged += Instance_NetworkChanged;

 private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (NetworkHelper.Instance.ConnectionInformation.IsInternetAvailable)
     {
         await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
         {
             IsConnected = true;
         });

     }
 }

 private async void Instance_NetworkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (NetworkHelper.Instance.ConnectionInformation.IsInternetAvailable)
     {
         await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
         {
             IsConnected = true;
         });
     }
     else
     {
         await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
         {
             IsConnected = false;
         });
     }
 }
```

**Xaml code**

```
<controls:DataGrid
    x:Name="MyDataGrid"

     ......

    >
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn
            Width="*"
            Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=DataContext.IsConnected, Mode=TwoWay}"
            FontSize="25"
            Header="ID"
            Tag="Id"
            Visibility="Visible"
            />
```

**Please Note**

we could not use it like the following, because it can't access root `DataContext` from second `DataTemplate` level.

```
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Test" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                <Button Content="Flag" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=DataContext.IsConnected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this too and I guess it would work, but I was really hoping for a simpler one-line solution to refresh a DataGrid that I could use whenever I need it. For example, in iOS there are multiple built-in functions you can call to refresh the data in a table or collection view, I figured DataGrid would have something similar.

Comment: That base on your design,and mvvm bind is provided way within uwp platform.